# Was ist eine »Waldung«?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

Ich singe in einem Chor, und wir studieren derzeit das Stück *Szenen aus Goethes Faust* von Robert Schumann ein.
Das Werk entstand zwischen 1844 und 1853, also 12 bis 21 Jahre nach Goethes Tod. In dem Werk sind einige Schlüsselszenen aus Goethes Faust vertont.
Leider habe ich Faust nie gelesen, und bin damit nicht sonderlich vertraut.¹

Jedenfalls gibt es in dem Stück, das wir bald aufführen werden, in der »dritten Abtheilung« den Satz »*№ 7. Faust’s Verklärung*«, mit der Unterschrift *Bergschluchten, Wald, Fels, Einöde. Heilige Anachoreten, gebirgauf vertheilt, gelagert zwischen Klüften*, der mit diesem vom Chor gesungenen Text beginnt:

> **Waldung**, sie schwankt heran,
>   Felsen, sie lasten dran,
>   Wurzeln sie klammern an,
>   Stamm dicht an Stamm hinan,
>   Woge nach Woge spritzt,
>   Höhle die tiefste schützt;
>   Löwen sie schleichen stumm
>   freundlich um uns herum,
>   ehren geweihten Ort
>   Heiligen Liebeshort.

Ich nehme an, dass diese Zeilen 1:1 aus Goethes Faust stammen.

Meine Frage:
Was ist mit *Waldung* gemeint? Ist das schlichtweg ein Wald?

---

<sup>¹ Goethe ist aus österreichischer Sicht ein ausländischer Autor und wird daher nicht so ausführlich unterrichtet, wie das vermutlich in Deutschland der Fall ist. In Österreich legt man eher Wert auf Raimund, Nestroy, Grillparzer, Musil, Zweig, Stifter, Schnitzler, usw.</sup>

Comment: _Faust II_ wird auch in Deutschland in der Schule wenig gelesen.

Comment: Und Du hast es in keinem Wörterbuch gefunden?

Comment: @userunknown: Ich bin gerade nicht daheim (sondern auf einem Proben-Seminar) und habe daher kein Wörterbuch zur Hand. Im Internet habe ich nichts gefunden.

Comment: @user unknown: Es steht zwar im Duden, der sich aber nicht um historischen Bedeutungen kümmert (vgl. [Scherbe](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Scherbe), was in _Faust I_ ‘Blumentopf’ heißt). Das DWB wiederum ist schwer zu lesen. Daher finde ich es nicht angebracht, es als „general reference“ vorauszusetzen.

Comment: Gut, dass wir in Deutschland weltoffener sind. Wir haben auch ausländische Autoren wie Zwei oder Dürrenmatt gelesen. Und wer darf eigentlich Kafka reklamieren?

Comment: @CarstenS: Die Frage nach Kafka ist sehr gut. In Österreich gelten nämlich sowohl Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart als auch Franz Kafka als österreichische Künstler. Nun ist es aber so, dass Mozart geborener Salzburger ist, Kafka aber geborener Prager. Salzburg gehörte zu Mozarts Lebzeiten nicht zu Österreich, heute aber schon. (Mozart starb 1791, Salzburg gehört erst seit 1805 zu Österreich). Prag hingegen gehörte zum größten Teil von Kafkas Lebzeiten zu Österreich, heute nicht mehr. (Kafka: 1883-1924; Prag gehört seit 1918 nicht zu Österreich).

Comment: (Fortsetzung) Es ist echt schwierig, ein allgemein gültiges Argument zu finden, das beide, Mozart wie auch Kafka, zu Österreichern macht. Aber vermutlich weil Mozart mehr Geld bringt, macht man es meist so, dass die heutigen Grenzen gelten.

Comment: @CarstenS: In meinem Fall kam hinzu, dass ich eine naturwissenschaftlich orientierte Schule besuchte (in der Physik und Chemie getrennte Fächer waren und wo Physik ein Hauptfach war). Deutsch hatte dort ohnehin keinen großen Stellenwert. Zweiter Grund: Unser Deutsch-Professor war Alkoholiker, der völlig überfordert war, und sich von den Schülern auf der Nase rumtanzen ließ. Er hat es einfach nicht geschafft, auch nur irgendwas zu unterrichten. Von Raimund und Nestroy spielte er Schallplatten mit Mitschnitten von Theateraufführungen vor, während wir Schüler taten wozu wir gerade Lust hatten.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Die heutigen Grenzen anzuwenden ist Blödsinn, sonst müsste man Kant als russischen Philosophen führen. Die ehemaligen Grenzen helfen aber auch umso weniger weiter, je weiter man in die Vergangenheit geht. Gryphius, Eichendorff und Hauptmann waren deutsche Dichter aus Schlesien - einer der drei müsste nach der Grenzregel als Österreicher gelten (Preisfrage: wer?). Wem bringt das was? Goethe wird in deutschen Schulen gelehrt, weil er der bedeutendste deutsch*sprachige* Dichter seiner Zeit und darüber hinaus war, und nicht weil Frankfurt und Weimar heute in Deutschland liegen.

Comment: Duden http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Waldung, Woxicon http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/waldung.php dict.cc https://www.dict.cc/?s=Waldung Wictionary https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Waldung - alle von Seite 1 der Googlesuche nach Waldung, alles Treffer, zero Misses. Was die Scherbe damit zu tun hat erschließt sich mir nicht.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das *Deutsche Wörterbuch* [erläutert](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=waldung):

> die ursprüngliche bedeutung ist die collective, ein gröszerer bezirk, der mit wald bestanden ist … vielfach steht *waldung* im gebrauch *wald* sehr nahe und wechselt namentlich im plur. beliebig mit diesem …

Demnach ja, es ist hier einfach ein Wald. Möglicherweise wurde *Waldung* aus metrischen Gründen gewählt.