# Are the works of Kafka considered German literature?

Tags: literature

I can't find a specific community for German literature so I will try my luck here. My guess is this community is populated by lovers of German language and German books :)

So, I came across a list of German authors and mentioned it on Twitter. A good friend caught the tweet and corrected me saying that Kafka wasn't German. My perception however, is that because Kafka wrote in German in my non-European eyes his works are German literature. I understand because I am not European the sociopolitical distinction between German - Czech - Austrian - Hungarian together with changing national boundaries during Kafka's entire lifetime are pretty lost on me.

My question is: how is German literature defined? What qualifies as German literature? Does the writer have to be a German citizen for their work to qualify as German literature, or merely sharing some cultural similarities across borders and writing in German enough?

I am asking as someone who has never been learning German in a formal setting.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: changed the phrasing to please some contributors. I do try…

Comment: Some relevant comments (in German): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26484/was-ist-eine-waldung#comment63624_26484

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about history of literature, cultural and educational policy etc., but not about the German language.

Comment: Oh. Tough crowd. I will try my luck outside of stackexchange then.

Comment: @chirlu I don't think this is off-topic. It's surely not as on-topic as most other questions, but it's still closely related to the German language and where else would you ask the question?

Comment: @Janek Bevendorff: Well, I don’t agree; as I said, it’s mostly politics etc. BTW, the question is also opinion-based (“How do you define German literature?”); there is no “correct” definition for what German literature is. – There probably is no place on SE where this question could be asked (even on Literature [1](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature), [2](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature), it would be too opinion-based); but that’s not necessary, either – it‘s completely fine for some questions not to be on-topic anywhere on SE.

Comment: Es mutet recht kafkaesk an, Franz Kafka nicht der deutschen Literatur zuordnen zu wollen.

Comment: @chirlu should I edit & rephrase the question to be "How is German literature defined?" I hope this community will tolerate an awkward phrasing or two, because English is not my native language.

Comment: @braaains: You should really ask that those people who believe the question is on-topic and answerable in an objective way.

Comment: Consider an analogy: Is "The Old Man and the Sea" considered English literature, or American literature?

Comment: @Benubird Actually, it depends. In the terms of Wikpedia: both, since there they talk about English-language literature under the lemma of [English literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_literature). The Encyclopedia Britannica, on the other hand, uses [another definition](http://www.britannica.com/art/English-literature). --- Beside: I wish the stability of "American" and "English" as a regional or national identifiers would have been a real analogy to "German".

Comment: @chirlu You’re right, in its current form this question is off-topic, because it’s asking whether Kafka or his works are considered *German* when it should have asked whether they’re considered **_deutsch_** (they’re certainly _deutschsprachig_).

Answer (score 15):

In German there is a distinction between *deutsche Literatur* (German literature) and *deutschsprachige Literatur* (literature written in German). The former would only include authors from Germany, while the latter expands to Austrians and Swiss as well. Thus, Kafka is part of the *deutschsprachige Literatur* (see German [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschsprachige_Literatur), for example).

Comment: Thank you! This is the kind of information I was looking for, as I am not heavily immersed in German culture.

Comment: By the way, there is also German language literature in other parts of the world beyond the three main countries. Examples are Kazakhstan, Belgium and Brazil.

Comment: what exactly in the german wikipedia?

Comment: People in Liechtenstein also speak German!

Comment: The reference to German Wikipedia contradicts your answer: [Deutsche Literatur](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Literatur) redirects to "Deutschsprachige Literatur", which in turn uses both terms as synonyms in its introductory sentence.

Comment: Martin Peters, RoflcoptrException: True, and much more examples (Romania...) can be found as well. My apologies if someone felt left out.

Comment: BЈовић: The article about Kafka himself.

Matthias: I think I'll disagree with the German wikipedia about that topic then. "Österreichische Literatur" (Austrian literature) and "Schweizer Literatur" (Swiss literature) are clearly a thing and describe literature from Austria or Switzerland. How exactly should we name literature from Germany if not with "Deutsche Literatur"? (There is a complaint on wiki's discussion page as well.)

Comment: @JanStephan Are Christa Wolf or Hermann Kant "from Germany"?  --- Apart from that: I agree that "Deutsche Literatur" _can_ mean "literature from Germany", but only with some context. Most of the time it is a synonym for "literature written in German", and I don't see a big problem with ambiguity here.

Answer (score 10):

**How do you define German literature?**

What do you mean by "you"? If you intend to collect some personal, individual convictions of German SE users who bother to write an answer - well, let's close this question as "primarily opinion-based". If, however, you want to address some unnamed community, assuming that their members agree on a definition of *German literature* - then, I am afraid, it depends. But let us first look on your second question.

**Does the writer have to be a German citizen for their work to qualify as German literature...?**

I think this can be answered - if it doesn't come with a specific temporal context - with a clear *No*. Simply for the lack of such a thing as "German citizenship" for long periods in history. This quote from the [German Wikipedia article on Germany](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschland#Begriffsgeschichte) illustrates the problem quite well [emphasis mine]:

> Nach der Niederlegung der Reichskrone 1806 dominierten das Kaisertum Österreich, das Königreich Preußen und der Rheinbund das staatliche Geschehen im **Vorstellungsraum Deutschlands**; nach 1815 folgte als die deutsche Nationalität sichernder Staatenbund der Deutsche Bund unter der Führung Österreichs.

"Germany" was then a term of the imaginative space, not of the real world. It's only since 1871 that we have a succession of political entities that can be called "Germany".

Now let's come back to "it depends". As you can see from the other answers and comments it depends on who you are asking ;-) But searching for references I mainly found indications that "Deutsche Literatur" is understood as "Deutschsprachige Literatur":

- [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Literatur) seems to treat "Deutsche Literatur" as synonym to "Deutschsprachige Literatur", both by redirection and by the introductory phrase.
- There is the term "Prager deutsche Literatur" (see [here](http://www.kafka.uni-bonn.de/cgi-bin/kafka_maindeee.html?Rubrik=prager_deutsche_literatur&Punkt=begriff) for a lengthy discussion in German about its definition) that is also referenced by the [Franz Kafka society](http://www.franzkafka-soc.cz/spolecnost/). The term would not make much sense if "deutsche Literatur" would normally be understood as "literature from Germany". I assume its creators would have explicitly used "Prager deutschsprachige Literatur" if they had seen a necessity for that.
- A couple of years ago a large anthology has been published under the title [Kanon. Die deutsche Literatur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Kanon). It also contains works by Austrian and Swiss authors - and Kafka. The title for sure is debatable, but I think it shows how the publishers expected the public to understand the term "Deutsche Literatur".

But there is also [Austrian literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austrian_literature) and [Swiss literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_literature) - how do you call literature from Germany then? Well, in a context where it is clear that we are speaking about the contemporary literaric production of different countries: German literature. (Remember: it depends...) But ottherwise, you could explicitly specify the country you are referring to: "Literatur der Bundesrepublik Deutschland / DDR / Weimarer Republik / ...". And what would be the use of putting all these very different political entities in one set and contrasting it with other German speaking parts of the world? There simply has been much more continuity in what language the adjective "deutsch" is referring to that to which nationality, political entity or region.

**tl;dr** You can safely say that the works of Franz Kafka belong to German literature ("deutsche Literatur"), unless there is a clear context where *German* would be rather understood as a nationality or regional attribute. If you want to avoid any discussions, call them works of literature in German language.

Comment: I didn't exactly mean "you" in the literal sense when I wrote the question. It escaped me that people can interpret the question as "anyone is invited to give their personal definition". English is not my first language, as I have explained in a comment under my question. I was typing the sentence the way it popped into my head, the way one would offhand ask a friend "How do you say '_____' in German?"

Comment: Double comment because app doesn't allow paragraphs. Thank you for the lengthy and informative reply. I did understand German literature as more language-based rather than nationality-based, so your answer has clarified my confusion. I also wish other book readers wouldn't be so anal about which writer is German and which isn't, and just focus on the language.

Answer (score 6):

I would consider Kafka as much and as little German literature as I would consider Mozart's works German. Nationality surely matters when analyzing the social and political circumstances under which these works were created, but in the end what people talk about is the language.

Kafka is very common subject material for German lessons in school, so from that point of view it's surely considered German or at least German-language literature. From a historical standpoint, however, I wouldn't call it German literature.

Comment: "I would ..." - it would be helpful if you could back your personal opinion with references and facts.

Comment: Well, I can't really. I just answered the question, how *I* would define it. My only evidence is Kafka as subject material in schools.

Comment: Thank you @JanekBevendorff. I find your answer useful because it gives me an idea of how German schools teach literature.